# 'merge' rows if they are duplicated in a table - SQLite

Tags: sqlite, duplicates

Table is the following:

```sql
CREATE TABLE UserLog(uid TEXT, clicks INT, lang TEXT)
```

Where `uid` field should be unique.

Here is some sample data:

```
|      uid      |  clicks |    lang    |
----------------------------------------
| "898187354"   |    4    |    "ru"    |
| "898187354"   |    4    |    "ru"    |
| "123456789"   |    1    |   <null>   |
| "123456789"   |    10   |    "en"    |
| "140922382"   |    13   |   <null>   |
```

As you can see, I have multiple rows with where the `uid` field is now duplicated. I would like for those rows to be *merged* in a following way:

`clicks` fields are added, and `lang` fields are updated if their previous value was `null`.

For the data shown above, it would look something like this:

```
|      uid      |  clicks |    lang   |
---------------------------------------
| "898187354"   |    8    |    "ru"   |
| "123456789"   |    11   |    "en"   |
| "140922382"   |    13   |   <null>  |
```

It seems that I can find many ways to simply delete duplicate data, which I do not necessarily want to do. I'm unsure how I can introduce logic in SQL statements that does this.

Comment: It's better to post sample data and expected results to clarify what you need.

Comment: "`uid` field is unique" vs "the `uid` field is now duplicated" -- something doesn't add up here. Is it unique or is it not?

Comment: @forpas I have posted sample and expected data

Comment: @stickybit Clarification, I meant that the `uid` field _should_ be unique. Thank you, the post has been edited.

Comment: What happens to the lang column when there are 2 not null rows?

Comment: @forpas it is arbitrary, i.e. can be set to whichever comes first. If there are more than two duplicates, where we have for example <null>, "en", "fa", it can also be set arbitrarily, but no <null> value must remain, so it is either "en" or "fa"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First update:

```
update userlog
set 
  clicks = (select sum(u.clicks) from userlog u where u.uid = userlog.uid),
  lang = (select max(u.lang) from userlog u where u.uid = userlog.uid)
where not exists (
  select 1 from userlog u
  where u.uid = userlog.uid and u.rowid < userlog.rowid
);
```

and then delete the duplicate rows that are not needed:

```
delete from userlog
where exists (
  select 1 from userlog u
  where u.uid = userlog.uid and u.rowid < userlog.rowid
);
```